# ¿como crear un switch case dentro de un recorrido en DATATABLES?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, datatables

Estoy pintando los datos traídos de la base de datos en `datatables`, el problema es que necesito validar un dato para poder pintar un `badge` en la `GUI`, y busco la forma de hacer con un `switch` ya que si uso un `if` se me hace muy extensa la validacion.

**CODIGO**

```
var rowNode = db_consultar_empleados
            .row.add([
                        resultado[i].emple_id,                          
                        resultado[i].emple_cedula,
                        resultado[i].emple_nombre,
                        resultado[i].emple_apellido,
                        (resultado[i].porcentaje == '80' && resultado[i].resultado_lider <= '25' || resultado[i].porcentaje == '100' && resultado[i].resultado_lider <= '60' ?
                        "<span class='badge' style='background: red'>" + resultado[i].resultado_lider + "%</span>"  :

                            (resultado[i].porcentaje == '80' && resultado[i].resultado_lider >= '26' && resultado[i].resultado_lider <= '45' || resultado[i].porcentaje == '100' && resultado[i].resultado_lider >= '61' && resultado[i].resultado_lider <= '89' ?
                            "<span class='badge' style='background: orange'>" + resultado[i].resultado_lider + "%</span>"  :
                            "<span class='badge' style='background: green'>" + resultado[i].resultado_lider + "%</span>" )),


                        resultado[i].detalle_per_id_area_empleado,
                        resultado[i].deteva_id
                    ])
                .draw()
            .node();
```

Aqui funciona validando con un `IF` pero la idea es poder hacer dentro de ese recorrido decir:

Que si en caso de que la 'variable' `resultado[i].area` sea `igual a 1` valide si el  `porcentaje es 80 y el resultado  es <= 25` o si `porcentaje es 100 y el resultado <= 60` que pinte un `badge de color rojo` y de igual manera validar lo mismo pero en caso de que `resultado[i].area` `igual a 2`.

Comment: Pues el `switch ... case` se hace como se hace un  `switch ... case` , en la parte del programa donde quieres usarlo para reemplazar a  los `if... then... else` aunque si son muchas condiciones yo validaría usando una función a la que le pasaría los datos a evaluar y que ella me devuelva el resultado como tengo que presentarlo.

Comment: Hola @A.Cedano, por tal motivo hice la pregunta por que hacer un switch claramente es muy facil pero al realizarlo dentro de lo que se esta recorriendo en la varible del datatables el editor empieza a mostar errores.

Comment: Los errores imagino que son porque el `switch...` está mal, a veces un símbolo de más o de menos. Como te decía, si el `switch` es muy extenso, yo lo haría fuera, en una función. De ese modo el código queda más claro y más fácil de analizar.

Comment: Ejemplo de una función, fuera del bloque de código actual: `function validar ($dato1, $dato2) {  switch ... case 1: return resultado; break;  case 2 return resultado; break; ...}` y para llamarla desde dentro del código : `$resultado=validar($dato1, $dato2);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debido a que tu código que muestras esta dentro de un `for` y estas renderizando informacion en la tabla no puedes hacer el `switch` donde tienes ahora el `if` lineal, lo mejor es hacerlo fuera, de esta forma:

```
for(let i = 0; i < resultado.length; i++){
  var res = "";
  switch (resultado[i].area) {
    case 1:
      if (validacion correspondiente) {
        res = "<span class='badge' style='background: red'>" + resultado[i].resultado_lider + "%</span>"
      }
      break;

    case 2:
      if (validacion correspondiente) {
        //...
      }
      break;
  }

  var rowNode = db_consultar_empleados
    .row.add([
      resultado[i].emple_id,
      resultado[i].emple_cedula,
      resultado[i].emple_nombre,
      resultado[i].emple_apellido,

      res,//aqui no se puede aplicar el switch debido a que se renderiza la informacion y genera errores

      resultado[i].detalle_per_id_area_empleado,
      resultado[i].deteva_id
    ])
    .draw()
    .node();
}
```

Comment: Hola @JuankGlezz, gracias por el interes, una consulta, la variable datos.lenght de donde la sacas? y el switch como lee resultados si se esta definiendo la variable datos? Un Saludo.

Comment: @JDavid es el total de registros que tiene `resultado`